# Angular 4 Tree Grid/Tabular Data with Radio Button selection

Tags: json, angular, typescript, radio-button, treegrid

I am working on a Angular 4 code where i need to create a table/grid structure UI with expanded selection and every item has radio button.
Below is the Exact UI which i want 
example

[image]

and I also have below format input data in my Json file

`{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "India",
    "Description": "India",
    "ParentId": 0,
    "SubGroup": [
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Mumbai",
            "Description": "Mumbai",
            "ParentId": 1,}
]
}`

Please tell me which Library i can use or how i can achieve this UI with Angular 4.

Comment: Maybe you wanna check ng2-tree from Volar Software. https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree

Comment: Thanks for this,But i want to do this in the Table format.

Answer (score 1):

[PrimeNg Tree Table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable) Can be a good choice. Good comunity support also there.

Comment: I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my answer.